# Find expression for $dy/dx $ + state where it is valid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

hopefully you guys can shed some insight into this question I'm working on.

Given

$xy+y^{2}-e^{x^{2}} = 6$

find an expression for $dy/dx$ and state where it is valid.

So, what I did was differentiate it, which resulted in:

$x+3y-2xe^{x^{2}} = 0 $

Although I am unsure whether this is correct, and I do not understand the state where it is valid. Any help or direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$xy+y^2 - e^{x^{2}}=6---(1)$

Differentiate with respect to $x$ to get

$y+xy'+2yy' - 2xe^{x^{2}}=0$

$y'(x+2y)=2xe^{x^{2}}-y$

$\displaystyle y'=\frac{2xe^{x^{2}}-y}{x+2y}---(2)$

Solving $(1)$ we have

$\displaystyle y=\frac{-x\pm \sqrt{x^2+4e^{x^{2}}+24}}{2}$

Put $y$ in $(2)$

$\displaystyle y'=\frac{2xe^{x^{2}}-\left(\frac{-x\pm \sqrt{x^2+4e^{x^{2}}+24}}{2}\right)}{x+2\left(\frac{-x\pm \sqrt{x^2+4e^{x^{2}}+24}}{2}\right)}$

$\displaystyle y'=\frac{4xe^{x^{2}}+x\mp \sqrt{x^2+4e^{x^{2}}+24}}{{\pm 2\sqrt{x^2+4e^{x^{2}}+24}}}$

Since $\pm 2\sqrt{x^2+4e^{x^{2}}+24}$ is defined for all $\mathbb{R}$, we say that $y'$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah yes, woops. Thanks! Any insight on the "state where it's valid" ? Something like (x+2y =/ 0) ?